# Is there an "NServiceBus System" project template for VS2012

Tags: nservicebus

Is there a Visual Studio 2012 NServiceBus System project template? I can see there is one for VS2010 in the install tools folder: `/NServiceBus/v3.3.5/Tools/NServiceBusStudio.vsix`

I searched on NuGet, but couldn't find anything. Is the development for the VS2012 template in the works?

Answer (score 1):

Development of NServiceBus Studio for Visual Studio 2012 is in its final stages. 
A public Beta is due within the near future.

Comment: Any progress on this?  It is 2 months later now.

Comment: Any progress on this?

Comment: (urggh)...any progress on this?

Comment: I think Nservice bus project template is discontinued. They are no more maintaining this.